# Command like DedekindEta for Sage

Tags: modular-forms, maple, mathematica, sagemath

In Mathematica we have the command `DedekindEta` for computing values of the Dedekind eta function.

Is there an equivalent command for Sage or Maple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [this reference manual section](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/sage/modular/etaproducts.html) may be what you're looking for, and in particular (as a modular form, I guess) the function you seek seems to be [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/modmisc/sage/modular/etaproducts.html#sage.modular.etaproducts.qexp_eta), roughly.

Comment: If I am not wrong this command is not helpful for computing for example the value $\eta(i\2)$ isn't it?

Comment: You may be right; I am not too current on how to compute exact values of functions given by modular forms.  You may want to ask on https://ask.sagemath.org where more experts on this hang out.